# Uncaught TypeError: OneSignal.once is not a function

Tags: javascript, push-notification, onesignal

Hai i want to sent the push notifcation to the browsers. So i used the onesignal.

```
var OneSignal = OneSignal || [];
OneSignal.push(["init", {
    appId           :   "xxxxxxx",
    autoRegister    :   false, /* Set to true to automatically prompt visitors */
    subdomainName   :   "https://foxtaxi.onesignal.com",
    notifyButton    :   {
        enable: true /* Set to false to hide */
    }
}]);

OneSignal.push(function() {
    OneSignal.once("init", function(event) {
        alert("hhh");
    });
 });
```

But i am getting the **Uncaught TypeError: OneSignal.once is not a function**. If anyone knows about it please help me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Solution

You'll need to wrap your call with `OneSignal.push(function() { ... })`:

```
OneSignal.push(function() {
  /* ... */
});
```

---

Also, `OneSignal.once('init')` is not a valid event. The [supported events are described here](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/website-sdk-api#list-of-events).

### Explanation

The OneSignal SDK is loaded asynchronously on your page, e.g.:

```
<script src="https://cdn.onesignal.com/sdks/OneSignalSDK.js" async"></script>
```

You can read more about the async attribute [here](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/critical-rendering-path/adding-interactivity-with-javascript#parser-blocking-vs-asynchronous-javascript) and [here](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/BlockingJS).

Basically, a script without an `async` attribute stops the loading of the rest of the page while it is fetched and executed, but `async` scripts allow the rest of the page to load, while it is *eventually* fetched and executed. This presents a problem for page scripts that depend on the `OneSignal` existing. If the `OneSignal` variable does not yet exist, how can `OneSignal` be used?

Most of the OneSignal code examples begin with:

```
var OneSignal = window.OneSignal || [];
```

This says: create a OneSignal variable, and if OneSignal is loaded already assign it to the loaded instance, otherwise let OneSignal equal the empty array `[]`.

All arrays have a [`.push()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push), so at this point, the OneSignal variable is simply an array of functions we're pushing on to it.

When the SDK finally loads, the SDK [processes all the functions pushed so far and redefines `.push()`](https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Website-SDK/blob/03cd16cacb79ff6d37156878d4f59ebf31ad8044/src/OneSignal.js#L2050).

Comment: Hi jason. Thanks for the answer. Now i didn't get that console error. But when i put alert on the init function i didn't get that alert message. I have changed the code for the reference.

Answer (score 0):

```
OneSignal.push(function() {
    OneSignal.once("init", function(event) {
        // This callback fires only once when the event occurs, and does not refire
    });
});
```